# Horizontal parallax sliding content

Tags: javascript, html, parallax, horizontal-scrolling

I would love to create a horizontal parallax scrolling effect like this website below;
https://delassus.com/en/

But I don't really know how to start. Could anybody give me advice or a sample which looks like this?

Tried to duplicate the source files from this specific website (HTML,CSS,Javascript) but that gave me 404 errors.

Comment: Please respect time of other users, read [ask] and create [mre] with what you try and what you get

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.